# Problem installing Wine on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wine, winetricks

I have been going through all these solutions for days, with no luck as I'm not very tech-savvy, I had wine installed for playing Ren'Py games. But lately, I did something to try and make it work for RPG games, but now nothing works anymore, where do I start?

I tried removing it and reinstalling it again.

I have Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, when I check which version I have for wine, it says wine 32 missing.

```
lord@lord-OptiPlex-760:~$ wine --version
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
wine-3.0 (Ubuntu 3.0-1ubuntu1)
lord@lord-OptiPlex-760:~$ apt-get install wine32
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Comment: "apt-get install" requires `sudo`. Try again with `sudo`.

Comment: ok thank you , as i say im not very knowledgeable in tec terms , but eventually figured out you mean to put   sudo before apt get install wine 32 , and i get this ....Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 3):

You need root privileges to install new packages.  Try the following commands:

```
sudo apt install -f  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade  
sudo apt install wine64 wine32
```

Hope I've helped you.

Comment: yes , thank you so much , i appreciate that :) it works